# RecyclerView is not loading data

Tags: php, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to load my recyclerview with data coming from php. But for some unknown reason it is not loading any data. I've used this same code for other activities, it works fine for that but for this activity it just stays blank. I've tested my php file it works fine.

Here is my code for activity:

```
public class Match_scoring extends AppCompatActivity implements TeamAdapter.onItemClickListener {

    public static String URL_data;
    public static String p_id;
    public static String p_name;

    TeamAdapter adapter;
    EditText editText;
    List<TeamItems> list_items;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Button subs;

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_scoring);

        URL_data = "http://prasaurus.com/trial_db_php/tbl_show_201_0_data.php";

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.url);
        tv.setText(URL_data);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mSearch_match);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.total_players_recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list_items = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new TeamAdapter(list_items,getApplicationContext());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(Match_scoring.this);

        loadRecyclerViewData();

    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_data, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                    if (success == 1) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject_current = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            TeamItems teamItems = new TeamItems(
                                    jsonObject_current.getString("player_id"),
                                    jsonObject_current.getString("player_name"),
                                    jsonObject_current.getString("player_dob"),
                                    jsonObject_current.getString("position"),
                                    jsonObject_current.getString("team_id")
                            );
                            list_items.add(teamItems);
                        } adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void filter(String text){
        ArrayList<TeamItems> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (TeamItems item : list_items){
            if(item.getPlayer_name().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        TeamItems clickedItem = list_items.get(position);

        Intent details = new Intent(Match_scoring.this,ScoringDetails.class);
        p_id = clickedItem.getPlayer_id();
        p_name = clickedItem.getPlayer_name();

        startActivity(details);


    }
}
```

Here is the layout `XML` file for the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Match_scoring">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mSearch_match"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:hint="Search Player"

        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/total_players_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/mSearch_match"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/substitute"
        android:text="SUBS"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/total_players_recyclerView"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/substitute"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/url"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my php script:

```
<?php
$servername = "prasaurus.com";
$username = "prasauru_fand";
$password = "[DB-PASSWORD]";
$dbname = "prasauru_trial_db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$pair_id=$_POST['pair_id'];
$fixture=$_POST['fixture'];

$response = array();

$query = "select * from tbl_201_0_match_details";



$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $response['success'] = 1;
    $Data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($Data , $row);
    }
        $response['Data'] = $Data;
}
else {
    $response['success'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'No data';
}

echo json_encode($response);    
mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: @mehul There is no error, my recycler view is just blank. Activity loads but there is no item in recyclerview

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this problem so many times. as `notifyDatasetChanged()` on adapter does not work as indended.

Just create simple function in recyclerview adapter and call a function when data is available from webcall

```
public void updateDataset(List<Model> updatedData){
yourListWhichInflateData=updatedData;
notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Call above function using adapter instance whenever data is available in activity or updated.